# Importing a whole text file in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, file-io, io, jtextarea

I am kinda new to Java. I am creating a simple program to read a text file and put its contents into text area in a java swing frame. My file looks like this

```
Hello World!
What a beautiful World!
```

For the java frame I created a button and an action for the button to import the text from the text file into the text area when clicked. The problem is that the program only reads the second line of the text file "What a beautiful world!" I know it is probably a tiny stupid mistake, but I couldn't figure it out. here is my code for the class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaGui {

    Scanner scnr;
    static String fileText;

    public void openfile(){
        try{
            scnr = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\13195\\New JavaGui\\abc.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File Not Found. Try Again!");
        }
    }

    public void readfile(){
         while (scnr.hasNextLine()){
             fileText = scnr.nextLine();
             System.out.println(fileText);
         }
        scnr.close();
    }
}
```

And here is the class with main method:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GuiFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JTextArea jtxt = new JTextArea(30, 30);
    private JFrame fr = new JFrame("Framework");
    private JButton btn = new JButton("View Text");

    static String t;

    public GuiFrame(){
        fr.add(jtxt);
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        fr.add(btn);

        //Frame
        fr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        fr.setSize(50,50);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GuiFrame();

        JavaGui fr = new JavaGui();
        fr.openfile();
        fr.readfile();

        t = JavaGui.fileText;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btn){
            jtxt.setText(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`JTextComponent.read(Reader, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,java.lang.Object)).

Comment: General tips: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) `fr.setSize(50,50);` This is no better than a guess. Use `fr.pack();` for the exact right size.

Comment: Did the suggestion in my first comment work for you? Please don't forget to provide feedback. SO is a repository for use by all, including those who come looking for solutions later.

Comment: Your saving only one line of the file input in a String.  You need to either concatenate the input lines in one long String or better yet, save the file input lines in a String array or a List<String>.